# Arrays with attributes in Julia

Tags: numpy, julia

I am making my first steps in julia, and I would like to reproduce something I achieved with `numpy`.

I would like to write a new array-like type which is essentially an vector of elements of arbitrary type, and, to keep the example simple, an scalar attribute such as the sampling frequency `fs`.

I started with something like

```
type TimeSeries{T} <: DenseVector{T,}
    data::Vector{T}
    fs::Float64
end
```

Ideally, I would like:

1) all methods that take a `Vector{T}` as argument to take on `TimeSeries{T}`.

e.g.:

```
ts = TimeSeries([1,2,3,1,543,1,24,5], 12.01)
median(ts)
```

2) that indexing a `TimeSeries` always returns a `TimeSeries`:

```
ts[1:3]
```

3) built-in functions that return a `Vector` to return a `TimeSeries`:

```
ts * 2
ts  + [1,2,3,1,543,1,24,5]
```

I have started by implementing `size`, `getindex` and so on, but I definitely do not see how it could be possible to match points 2 and 3.

`numpy` has a quite comprehensive way to doing this: http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.subclassing.html. `R` also seems to allow linking attributes `attr()<-` to arrays.

Do you have any idea about the best strategy to implement this sort of "array with attributes".

Comment: I totally agree that redefining all methods that already work with Vector is tedious.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe I'm not understanding, why is for say point 3 it not sufficient to do

```
(*)(ts::TimeSeries, n) = TimeSeries(ts.data*n, ts.fs)
(+)(ts::TimeSeries, n) = TimeSeries(ts.data+n, ts.fs)
```

As for point 2

```
Base.getindex(ts::TimeSeries, r::Range) = TimeSeries(ts.data[r], ts.fs)
```

Or are you asking for some easier way where you delegate all these operations to the internal vector? You can clever things like

```
for op in (:(+), :(*))
    @eval $(op)(ts::TimeSeries, x) = TimeSeries($(op)(ts.data,x), ts.fs)
end
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for that, can you think of any way of doing that automatically for all function likely to be used on vectors (e.g. if `T` is a `Float`, one may apply `sin(TimeSeries)` and be guaranteed to a new `TimeSeries`)?

Comment: It would be great if Julia had some `subclass` functionality like Python. Redefine everything doesn't scale well.

Comment: There are open issues on how to make this better, e.g. https://github.com/JuliaLang/julia/pull/3292 and things it links to. @QuentinGeissmann, there is no way to do it without some intervention on your part because its ambiguous what it'd mean. That proposal I just linked where you "delegate" to the internal vector is a good approach to resolving the ambiguity with minimal effort.